# Save list items in QSettings

Tags: python, pyside2, qsettings

I am trying to save a list using `QSettings`, in which I code it as follows: `settings.setValue('ids', id_list)`

However, if there is only 1 item in the id_list, as I relaunch my code, the to-be-loaded settings for `ids` are capturing it as a string value instead of a list.

The following is how I have coded to store the values:

```py
settings = QtCore.QSettings('MyTest', 'Itemize')
id_list = []
for item_id in item_list:
    id_list.append(item_id)
settings.setValue('ids', id_list)
```

When I tried to rewrite it as:

```py
settings.value('ids', [], 'QStringList')
```

I got an error:

```py
TypeError: PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.value(): too many arguments #
```

Comment: what is the value of `item_list`?

Comment: The values are something as follows: `[u'541e-fe83-430d-9428-8595', u'b569-e7bb-4a4d-a8f6-4ed0']`

Comment: In PyQt, [there is a third argument to `value`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt_qsettings.html) for specifying the type, but [PySide doesn't support it](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.value). In C++ this isn't needed because the type can be specified via `QVariant`. But PySide doesn't support that either, so I would say this is a bug. Without one or the other, there is no way to distinguish between a single element list and a string.

Comment: @ekhumoro You're right, it's another bug from PySide2

Comment: I should also point out this only affects lists of *strings*. So a possible work-around is to put the list inside another list (e.g. `[['foo']]`) and then read it with `settings.value('ids', [[]])[0]`. It seems that the PySide devs are aware of the problem, because their docs show a similar kind of problem when storing an `int`. However, this does not happen on Windows because (by default) the registry is used to store the values. I think it is only when ini files are used that this issue arises.

Comment: @ekhumoro In Windows you do not have that problem? Could you link the PySide documentation that you point out? If you check the .ini it is saved as csv: `ids=a,b,c`, and when it saves a list with a single string element it saves it as: `ids=a` causing the problem. On the other hand I have reported it https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1010

Comment: @eyllanesc See the warning [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html#PySide2.QtCore.PySide2.QtCore.QSettings.value). I haven't actually tested any of this on Windows with PySide, so I'm not sure of the exact current behaviour. But the Registry should behave differently. I don't know what happens on Mac. But to be clear: this problem is only guaranteed to occur on all platforms when using INI files (which is the default on Linux).

Comment: @ekhumoro I see that the problem is caused because in the case of string it uses csv format , however when using another type of data it uses QDataStream to store it, for example in the case of `[1]` it saves it as `ids=@Variant(\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x1)`, instead with `["1"]` it saves it as `ids=1` which is the same format used for a string `"1"`

Comment: @eyllanesc The real issue is that PySide cannot return a `QVariant`. In C++,  you must always explicitly convert the value to whatever type you want. But in PySide, the value is automatically converted to a python type before it is returned. This is unpythonic, because it is effectively guessing when faced with ambiguous values.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the suggestions and sorry for not getting back on this. In the end, I tried to 'cheat' for a single item, by using `isinstance`. If it is `unicode`, I convert it into a list item eg. `[singleItem]` so as to get by with the issue.